# text in tkinter not working

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

i am trying to make a program that will have a big multiline entry in tkinter python 3.5, but i cant get the text to be saved as a variable:
i have tried:

```
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText  
root = Tk()  
var = StringVar()  
def go():  
    print(var.get())  
big_entry = ScrolledText(root, textvariable=var).pack()  
button = Button(root, text='PRINT', command=go).pack()  
root.mainloop()
```

but this doesnt seem to work, and it tells me that 'textvariable' is an unknown option can you please help me but bear in mind that i am only 13 and am relatively new to coding so keep your answeres simple

Comment: find documentation and check `ScrolledText` options.

Comment: btw: `pack()` returns `None` so you assign `None` to `big_entry` and `button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrolledText` doesn't use textvariable.

You have to use `insert()` and `get()`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText  

# --- functions ---

def go():  
    print(st.get(0.0, tk.END))  

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()  

st = ScrolledText(root)
st.pack()
st.insert(0.0, 'Hello World!')

btn = tk.Button(root, text='PRINT', command=go)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without importing tkinter as tk but by doing from tkinter import *?

Comment: yes, you can.  do it. (I prefer `import tkinter as tk` because I can see which element belong to tkinter module)

Answer (score 0):

you should type the following:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

def go():
    print(text.get(0.0, END)) #you need  to get the current value from line 0 letter 0 to the end

text = ScrolledText(root)
text.pack()

btn = Button(root, text='GO', command=go)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code above of your Python file:

```
from tkinter import scrolledtext
```

Comment: This answer is very brief, and is just code with no explanation.  Can you explain it, please?  Exceedingly brief code-only answers like this are often recommended for deletion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it is useful to note what new information this answer brings, and to address the passage of time if it is relevant (new version of software, etc.).